# Javascript memorise HTML tag contents and replace after duration

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that copies a Server IP to the client's clipboard via a .swf solution. As you can see it replaces the Copy IP button with a success 'Copied' message. How would I go about having that Copy IP button return after 5 seconds of displaying the success message, so the user can copy and paste multiple IP addresses from that page, copying the same one more than once.

```
    <script src="/assets/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function addCopyHandler(id) {
          var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById(id) );
          client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
          // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );
              client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
                  // `this` === `client`
                  // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
                  event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check text-success'></i> Copied";
                  event.target.style.textDecoration = "none";
                  event.target.style.color = "#3c763d";
                  event.target.style.cursor = "default";
              });
          });
        }
        <?php if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {$pagenum = 1;} else {$pagenum = $_GET['page'];}?>
        for(var i = <?php echo $limit_start;?>; i <= <?php echo $limit_amount*$pagenum;?>; i++) {
            addCopyHandler("copy-" + i);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a setTimeout inside the `client.on` function. Because of how JS closures work it will have access to the `event` object even though `setTimeout` is asynchronous and will execute 5 seconds later:

```
    function addCopyHandler(id) {
      var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById(id) );
      client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
      // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );
          client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
              // `this` === `client`
              // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
              event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check text-success'></i> Copied";
              event.target.style.textDecoration = "none";
              event.target.style.color = "#3c763d";
              event.target.style.cursor = "default";
              setTimeout(function(){
                  event.target.innerHTML = "Copy IP";
                  event.target.removeAttribute("style");
              },5000);
          });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` function. It's used to execute a command after the specified delay (in milliseconds).

```
client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
                  // `this` === `client`
                  // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
                  event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check text-success'></i> Copied";
                  event.target.style.textDecoration = "none";
                  event.target.style.color = "#3c763d";
                  event.target.style.cursor = "default";
                  setTimeout(function(){
                      event.target.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Copy";
                  },5000);

          });
```